# Multi Tenant Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Looking for an easy way build multi tenant razor page.  Looking for the url pattern to be like `\{Tenant}\{Page}` for all pages in an area.  Its fairly easy to add a route param at the end via RazorPagesOptions Conventions.  How do you add the param at the beginning?

Comment: Similar to https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7779 : *However, you should look into [`Razor Pages Conventions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.0) feature as that will enable you to write your own convention and implement the custom routing you're interested in.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [IPageRouteModelConvention interface](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions#ipageroutemodelconvention#ipageroutemodelconvention) to prefix each route with a route parameter representing the tenant. Create a class that implements the interface, and then override the `Apply` method, something like the following (untested):

```
public class CustomPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = "{tenant}/" +  selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template ;
        }
    }
}
```

Then register your implementation in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new CustomPageRouteModelConvention());
})
```

Comment: I tested it and it works. Within the Apply method you can both modify the default routes and add others.

Comment: @mcb2k3 this does work great where you have tenant based versions, but what if you have a scenario where actually your tenants use 80% the same and if a tenant based version of the same resource exists then that should be used instead.